# Can JAXB handle multiple "root" elements?

Tags: jaxb

I have a schema similar to the following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="t1" type="t1Type"/>
    <xs:element name="t2" type="t2Type"/>
    <xs:element name="t3" type="t3Type"/>
</xs:schema>
```

At first I thought this was an invalid schema but all the checks I do online validate it. This means the person supplying the XML can send any (or all) the types listed and still conform to the schema.

How do I go about mapping and unmarshalling all the different possibilities using JAXB?

I have no idea which of them I will be recieving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to leverage a factory class annotated with `@XmlRegistry` (usually called `ObjectFactory`).  That class will contain a `create` method for each possible root element annotated with `@XmlElementDecl`. See this [article](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html) I wrote for more details and examples.

Comment: in the example provided you know which type you are receiving what happens if I have no idea? I could get any type back how do I unmarshall?

Comment: @Jackie - You do not need to know the type of object to perform the unmarshal operation.  If you don't know what you are unmarshalling you will need to do an `instanceof` of `getClass()` to determine what you have before you can perform any type specific calls on the data.